# I have two tables which I want to join in R based on date condition but it does not seem to work

Tags: r, date, merge, cartesian-product, sqldf

I have two tables that I want to merge in R based on two conditions, one of them being difference between two days being between -30 and +30 days.

```
ID  FINAL_AMOUNT    ProcedureDate
10001282    19320   3/22/2017 1:44
10001282    37103   3/23/2017 11:11
10001282    22423   3/22/2017 19:49

ID  ResultDate  Amount 2
10001282    4/3/2017 6:25   0.4
10001282    3/27/2017 5:33  150.99
10001282    3/29/2017 5:50  116.71
10001282    4/5/2017 7:27   150.99
10001282    3/27/2017 5:33  0.4
10001282    3/29/2017 5:50  0.5
10001282    4/3/2017 6:25   150.99
10001282    4/5/2017 7:27   0.4
10001282    4/5/2017 7:27   0.4
10001282    4/5/2017 7:27   150.99
10001282    3/27/2017 5:33  0.4
10001282    3/29/2017 5:50  0.5
10001282    4/3/2017 6:25   150.99
10001282    4/3/2017 6:25   0.4
10001282    3/27/2017 5:33  150.99
10001282    3/29/2017 5:50  116.71
```

I want a Cartesian product with table 1 being my base table.
I am using the below code, but since the day difference is not being calculated correctly I don't get the desired results.

`library(sqldf)`

```
sqldf("SELECT a.*,b.*,(b.ResultDate-a.ProcedureDate)as daydiff from table1 as a left join table2 as b
              on a.ID=b.ID
              and (-30)<=b.ResultDate-a.ProcedureDate<=(30)" )
```

Thanks

Comment: If the dates are actually character strings then you can't subtract character strings from each other in R or in SQL.  Convert them to Date class first. in R.  Also please review [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified what result you get, when you calculate

```
b.ResultDate-a.ProcedureDate
```

is it only the number of days? First check this, by looking at what's in your daydiff column in the result-set. If not, you might need some casting to get the difference in days.

apart from that you could use the abs() function, to make the resulting difference of b.ResultDate-a.ProcedureDate always positive and have

```
abs(b.ResultDate-a.ProcedureDate) <= 30
```

as argument.
Aparat from that it would be easier, if you would have provided a complete example that one could use to check if the given answer is correct [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2582968)